# Finding a common unique order

Tags: c++, qt, optimization

For optimization purposes, I have to find a common order from given several orders. I load a file there every line is users with its action orders as indexes of actions.

I want to implement a method that returns a common order:

Input to the method: Is the users input order (the order they do actions[0,1,2,3,4])

```
      user1         0,1,2,4,3
      user2         0,1,2,3,4
      user3         0,2,1,3,4
      user4         0,1,3,2,4
      ...
```

I would like to find the unique common/global order. I want to find the order which most of the users prefer.

How to implement such a method or algorithm?

I am writing the code in C++ with Qt.

Any helps are appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: What does common order mean? What would it be in your example above with 4 users?

Comment: Common order in the example above would be: 0,1,2,3,4. The order where most of the users do actions sequentially. I feel like I am explaining correctly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you store your orders in a `std::vector<int>`, a standard solution to your problem is to use [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) to find the median item across all your orders.

**Example:**

```
  // Our orders
  std::vector<int> o1 = { 0,1,2,4,3 };
  std::vector<int> o2 = { 0,1,2,3,4 };
  std::vector<int> o3 = { 0,2,1,3,4 };
  std::vector<int> o4 = { 0,1,3,2,4 };

  // Regroup items by type
  std::vector<int> item1 = { o1[0] , o2[0], o3[0], o4[0] };
  std::vector<int> item2 = { o1[1] , o2[1], o3[1], o4[1] }; 
  std::vector<int> item3 = { o1[2] , o2[2], o3[2], o4[2] }; 
  std::vector<int> item4 = { o1[3] , o2[3], o3[3], o4[3] };

  // Lookup median elements
  std::nth_element(item1.begin(), item1.begin() + item1.size()/2, item1.end());
  std::nth_element(item2.begin(), item2.begin() + item2.size()/2, item2.end());
  std::nth_element(item3.begin(), item3.begin() + item3.size()/2, item3.end());
  std::nth_element(item4.begin(), item4.begin() + item4.size()/2, item4.end());

  std::cout << "Most wanted item 1 is " << item1[item1.size()/2] << '\n';
  std::cout << "Most wanted item 2 is " << item2[item2.size()/2] << '\n';
  std::cout << "Most wanted item 3 is " << item3[item3.size()/2] << '\n';
  std::cout << "Most wanted item 4 is " << item4[item4.size()/2] << '\n';
```

**Output:**

> Most wanted item 1 is 0
>
> Most wanted item 2 is 1
>
> Most wanted item 3 is 2
>
> Most wanted item 4 is 3

Live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c7eada3c1aac59f).

Comment: Hi, thanks. The results are promising, but could you please, explain from //lookup median elements ? I tried to figure out, but could not.

Comment: The solution will potentially return such an order: 0,2,1,4,4 for the input orders:                                                                                                                          std::vector<int> o1 = { 0,2,1,4,3 };
      std::vector<int> o2 = { 0,2,1,3,4 };
      std::vector<int> o3 = { 0,2,1,4,3 };
      std::vector<int> o4 = { 0,1,3,2,4 };

Comment: How to fix when there are two same values? I want to have 0,2,1,4,3 since 4 is already taken?

Comment: Maybe the solution could be to get the second item median value?

Comment: Simply remove the median element from the next vectors once it it taken ?

Comment: I will try that, guess easier to delete than to take second value